# Using OpenMP threads and std::(experimental::)simd to compute the Mandelbrot set

Tags: c++, g++, openmp, simd, c++-experimental

I am looking to implement a simple Mandelbrot set plotter using different kind of HPC paradigms, showing their strengths and weaknesses and how easy or difficult their implementations are. Think of GPGPU (CUDA/OpenACC/OpenMP4.5), threading/OpenMP and MPI. And use these examples to give programmers new to HPC a handhold and to see what the possibilities are. Clarity of code is more important than getting the absolute top performance out of the hardware, that's the second step ;)

Because the problem is trivial to parallelize and modern CPUs can gain a huge amount of performance using vector instructions, I also want to combine OpenMP and SIMD. Unfortunately, simply adding a `#pragma omp simd` does not yield satisfying results and using intrinsics is not very user friendly or future proof. Or [pretty](https://github.com/skeeto/mandel-simd/blob/master/mandel_avx.c).

Fortunately, work is being done to the C++ standard such that it should be easier to generically implement vector instructions, as mentioned in the TS: ["Extensions for parallelism, version 2"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4808.pdf), specifically section 9 on data-parallel types. A WIP implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/VcDevel/std-simd), which is based on VC which can be found [here](https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc).

Assume that I have the following class (which has been changed to make it a bit simpler)

```
#include <stddef.h>

using Range = std::pair<double, double>;
using Resolution = std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>;

class Mandelbrot
{
    double* d_iters;
    Range d_xrange;
    Range d_yrange;
    Resolution d_res;
    std::size_t d_maxIter;
    
public:
    Mandelbrot(Range xrange, Range yrange, Resolution res, std::size_t maxIter);
    ~Mandelbrot();

    void writeImage(std::string const& fileName);
    void computeMandelbrot();
private:
    void calculateColors();
};
```

And the following implementation of `computeMandelbrot()` using OpenMP

```
void Mandelbrot::computeMandelbrot()
{
    double dx = (d_xrange.second - d_xrange.first) / d_res.first;
    double dy = (d_yrange.second - d_yrange.first) / d_res.second;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (std::size_t row = 0; row != d_res.second; ++row)
    {
        double c_imag = d_yrange.first + row * dy;
        for (std::size_t col = 0; col != d_res.first; ++col)
        {
            double real = 0.0;
            double imag = 0.0;
            double realSquared = 0.0;
            double imagSquared = 0.0;
            double c_real = d_xrange.first + col * dx;

            std::size_t iter = 0;
            while (iter < d_maxIter && realSquared + imagSquared < 4.0)
            {
                realSquared = real * real;
                imagSquared = imag * imag;
                imag = 2 * real * imag + c_imag;
                real = realSquared - imagSquared + c_real;
                ++iter;
            }
            d_iters[row * d_res.first + col] = iter;
        }   
    }
}
```

We can assume that the resolutions both x and y directions are multiples of 2/4/8/.., depending on which SIMD instructions we use.

Unfortunately, there is very little information available online on `std::experimental::simd`. Nor any non-trivial examples as far as I could find.

In the Vc git repository, there is an implementation of the Mandelbrot set calculator, but it's quite convoluted and due to the lack of comments rather difficult to follow.

It is clear that I should change the data types of the doubles in the function `computeMandelbrot()`, but I'm unsure to what. The TS mentions two main new data types for some type T,

`native_simd = std::experimental::simd<T, std::experimental::simd_abi::native>;`

and

`fixed_size_simd = std::experimental::simd<T, std::experimental::simd_abi::fixed_size<N>>;`

Using `native_simd` makes the most sense, since I don't know my bounds at compile time. But then it is not clear to me what these types represent, is a `native_simd<double>` a single double or is it a collection of doubles on which a vector instruction is executed? And then how many doubles are in this collection?

If somebody could point me to examples where these concepts are used, or give me some pointers on how to implement vector instructions using std::experimental::simd, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Indeed, SIMD Mandelbrot is a hard tradeoff because each pixel has an independent exit condition.  You would need to manually vectorize, e.g. going until all pixels in a vector have "escaped" (but still recording *when* that first happened for each, e.g. with masking of an increment vector based on a compare result, if you want to colourize areas outside the set proper).  Or track which pixels are currently in a vector and replace one (with blends) when it escapes or something.  But that adds a lot of bookkeeping and shuffling overhead.

Comment: TL:DR: the data parallelism in Mandelbrot is hard to exploit with SIMD (except by naively always running to max iterations, very slow for pixels outside the set); you probably need a SIMD API that exposes more machine-specific operations.  Oh, this C++ extension has `bool any_of(const simd_mask<T, Abi>&)` and similar functions to test `vec1 < vec2` simd_mask results, like x86's `movmskpd` (`_mm_movemask_pd`) to let you branch on all / any of the per-element compare results.  So you could implement Mandelbrot with it, but I'd suggest picking a more SIMD-friendly problem first.

Comment: Like if you haven't done any SIMD stuff at all before, try vector dot-product.  Or linear search of an array.  (These are all orthogonal to OpenMP for thread-level parallelism, although an array dot-product can auto-vectorize with OMP simd with most compilers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the information! It was clear that one does not get perfect scaling in the Mandelbrot set, for the reasons you mention. For my purpose, if the naive implementation using `std::simd` is a pessimization instead of optimization, that would still be good. The same as using OpenACC, usually just adding a pragma equivalent to "just use the GPU" will lead to a severe performance penalty and often is much slower than a CPU implementation. Since I want to write some instructive examples, showing cases where you cannot trust the compiler to do the thing you thought it would do.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's also why the vector inner product isn't a very good example for me, because the compiler usually does the right thing. That would give the feeling that vectorization is just as simple as adding a pragma or just trust icc's autovectorization. Which sometimes is true, but often not.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am mostly looking for people who have played around with this new `std::simd` because so far I haven't been able to find any examples. Which makes sense, since it is still experimental. But that's also part of the reason of posting this question, so that other people wanting to use this construct can find this question.

Comment: If you're familiar with Intel intrinsics like `_mm_add_ps`, the implementation / design of std::simd appears fairly straightforward.  I don't expect using it will be too different from using intrinsics or existing C++ wrapper libraries such as [Agner Fog's VCL](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass), although I didn't look at how it exposes shuffles and blends.  x86 has a pretty idiosyncratic mix of shuffles available in hardware, some with only immediate control operands, a few with variable vector control operands.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic implementation, which works (as far as I can tell). The testing which elements of the vector have absolute value larger than 2 is done in a very cumbersome and inefficient way. There must be a better way to do this, but I haven't found it yet.

I get about a 72% performance increase on a AMD Ryzen 5 3600 and giving g++ the option `-march=znver2`, which is less than expected.

```
template <class T>
void mandelbrot(T xstart, T xend,
                T ystart, T yend)
{
    namespace stdx = std::experimental;

    constexpr auto simdSize = stdx::native_simd<T>().size();
    constexpr unsigned size = 4096;
    constexpr unsigned maxIter = 250;

    assert(size % simdSize == 0);
    unsigned* res = new unsigned[size * size];

    T dx = (xend - xstart) / size;
    T dy = (yend - ystart) / size;

    for (std::size_t row = 0; row != size; ++row)
    {
        T c_imag = ystart + row * dy;
        for (std::size_t col = 0; col != size; col += simdSize)
        {
            stdx::native_simd<T> real{0};
            stdx::native_simd<T> imag{0};
            stdx::native_simd<T> realSquared{0};
            stdx::native_simd<T> imagSquared{0};
            stdx::fixed_size_simd<unsigned, simdSize> iters{0};

            stdx::native_simd<T> c_real;
            for (int idx = 0; idx != simdSize; ++idx)
            {
                c_real[idx] = xstart + (col + idx) * dx;
            }

            for (unsigned iter = 0; iter != maxIter; ++iter)
            {
                realSquared = real * real;
                imagSquared = imag * imag;
                auto isInside = realSquared + imagSquared > stdx::native_simd<T>{4};
                for (int idx = 0; idx != simdSize; ++idx)
                {
                    // if not bigger than 4, increase iters
                    if (!isInside[idx])
                    {
                        iters[idx] += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // prevent that they become inf/nan
                        real[idx] = static_cast<T>(4);
                        imag[idx] = static_cast<T>(4);
                    }
                }

                if (stdx::all_of(isInside) )
                {
                    break;
                }        

                imag = static_cast<T>(2.0) * real * imag + c_imag;
                real = realSquared - imagSquared + c_real;
            }
            iters.copy_to(res + row * size + col, stdx::element_aligned);
        }

    }
    delete[] res;
}
```

The whole testing code (starting from `auto test = (...)`) compiles down to

```
  .L9:
  vmulps ymm1, ymm1, ymm1
  vmulps ymm13, ymm2, ymm2
  xor eax, eax
  vaddps ymm2, ymm13, ymm1
  vcmpltps ymm2, ymm5, ymm2
  vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rsp+160], ymm2
  jmp .L6
.L3:
  vmovss DWORD PTR [rsp+32+rax], xmm0
  vmovss DWORD PTR [rsp+64+rax], xmm0
  add rax, 4
  cmp rax, 32
  je .L22
.L6:
  vucomiss xmm3, DWORD PTR [rsp+160+rax]
  jp .L3
  jne .L3
  inc DWORD PTR [rsp+96+rax]
  add rax, 4
  cmp rax, 32
  jne .L6
```

Comment: Note that compares return a vector of all-0 or all-1, i.e. integer 0 / -1.  `iters -= compare;` increments by 0 or 1, i.e. `-(-1)`.  You want the asm to be `vcmpltps` / `vpsubd` using the FP compare result as a vector of int32_t or uint32_t, so you may need to do some casting to keep the compiler happy about types.

Comment: @PeterCordes On my system it is a vector of all 0's or all 1's (ie positve). So I can just do `iters[idx] += isInside[idx]` But then I still have the problem with the divergence which eventually causes NaN's... I will play around with it a bit more, any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: That's not what I get.  `auto foo (stdx::native_simd<float> v) { return v == v; }` compiles to a function that just does `cmpeqps %xmm0, %xmm0` / `ret`.  Thus it's returning a vector of all-1 bits, which represents an integer `-1`.  (as per Intel's asm manual https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpps).  You'd have to do something else to convert that to a vector of `0x00000000` or `0x00000001` instead of `0xffffffff`

Comment: If I print out test elementwise, i.e. `std::cout << test[idx]` [0:idx:test.size() - 1], then I get 0's or 1's. See also this example: https://godbolt.org/z/qPxeza Maybe we mean something else?

Comment: You've shown that *scalar* element access to a compare result comes out as `bool`, but there's almost certainly some way to get access to the compare-result *vector* directly, without booleanizing it to 0 / 1.  Like reinterpreting it to a `native_simd<unsigned>` vector or something.  Unless they crippled that to enable AVX512 compatibility, where a mask truly is an integer bitmask, not vector elements?  Hmm, apparently the C++ standard specifies `simd_mask<T>` as having bool elements, and even its `copy_to` is as-if using element access. memcpy works but is a hack: https://godbolt.org/z/xqb5rW

Comment: The internal object representation of `simd_mask<T>` is what we want, but IDK if there's a portable way to get it so you can just subtract it as an integer.  /sigh, attempts at portability frequently end up making some useful tricks impossible by creating a mismatch between the abstract API and what the machine can really do.  (For all vector ISAs except AVX512)

Comment: I have written the author of the library an email, hopefully he can give some pointers how to do it properly!

Comment: Good idea; I was thinking of posting an SO question to ask how one was supposed to `std::simd` to get a compiler to emit `cmpps xmm0, xmm1` / `psubd xmm2, xmm0`.  Worst case maybe your supposed to write a masked `v += 1` increment and depend on the compiler optimizing it back to this (if you don't have AVX512 to let it compile to a masked increment directly).  Which in practice I'd be worried wouldn't happen, and you'd get nasty overcomplicated asm.